# Angular Meta Tag zero result in Meta tag analyser

Tags: angular5, meta

I am using Meta and Title service to add dynamic meta description and title and I was able to view the result when I inspect the element but in the Meta tag analyzer it show zero result.

Any idea about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The analyzer tool you are using probably analyzes the HTML document and thus (like many search engines) will not pick up on any meta or title elements you inject dynamically using JavaScript.

Comment: can you please suggest to me how to achieve my problem? how can I add dynamic meta description and title and also I was able to view the result in meta tag analyzer?

Comment: Write them with HTML instead of JavaScript.

Comment: so I will add it statically? but angular has only one index.

Comment: This is why Angular is not well suited to websites which have different pages they want search engines to index.

Comment: so there is no other way but to add the Tag statically in HTML, thank you for your answer really appreacited

Comment: There is an other way. You should look into server-side rendering.

Comment: William can you add some link or example on that server-side rendering